# how to use common onCreateContextMenu for multiple fragments in android

Tags: android

I have two fragments class like :
**

```
public class ActiveChatsFragment extends HomeListFragment
public class ContactsFragment extends HomeListFragment
```

**

I want to create context menu for both the fragments.
But i want to put the **onCreateContextMenu** function in **HomeListFragment** so that a common function can be used for creating menu of both the fragments.
Although the menu to be created for both the fragments are different.

So if i put the **onCreateContextMenu** function in **HomeListFragment**
how will i know whether the call has come from **ContactsFragment** or **ActiveChatsFragment** ?
Is there any way to identify that ?

Thanks

Comment: start contextual menu through parent activity only.

Answer (score 0):

you may do something like this.

place this method on the HomeListFragment

```
public String whichFragment(){
    return "HomeListFragment";
}
```

then override that method in both ActiveChatsFragment and ContactsFragment.

in ActiveChatsFragment

```
@Override
public String whichFragment(){
    return "ActiveChatsFragment";
}
```

in ContactsFragment

```
@Override
public String whichFragment(){
    return "ContactsFragment";
}
```

now you can call that method whenever you want it.